# Why does container in html not show background color in some cases?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background-color of div with class=container but its not working Below is the code. I am not able to understand how background color and the position elements are linked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color:hotpink;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
background-color:green;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <p><b>Note: </b>When aligning using the position property, always include the !DOCTYPE declaration! If missing, it can produce strange results in IE browsers.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine? https://plnkr.co/edit/QPEs6Uwbw8Lyxq5WkwWy?p=preview

Comment: @SatejS OP is using green color in BG of container calss... check his code...

Comment: The problem is that, with only an absolutely positioned child for content, the outer div collapses to height 0. So it's there, you just don't see it.

Comment: @Talib Shaikh Can you please let us know why are you `position` property for `container` & .`right`??

Comment: @SunilGehlot, sorry my bad!

Comment: Along the lines of what @MrLister  said ,add an element before the right element. https://plnkr.co/edit/QPEs6Uwbw8Lyxq5WkwWy?p=preview

Comment: With the html added, change position to absolute for 'container' and background will be applied.
To achieve this layout use of positions is not required though.

Comment: By the way, off topic, but the remark in your source is only partially correct. In reality, you should _always_ include the doctype declaration, no matter the circumstances!

Comment: @Mr Lister: If it makes you feel better, this example is indeed from W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mppfbjcr/)...

I have removed `position` property for `.container` & `.right` and used `float:right` for `.right` class, check code below.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:hotpink;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color:green;
    width: 100%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}

.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <p><b>Note: </b>When aligning using the position property, always include the !DOCTYPE declaration! If missing, it can produce strange results in IE browsers.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```